# Why not serving static files with Django in a production environment?

Tags: python, django, apache, static, settings

I came across the following example for `settings.py`:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

and was told:

> The static() helper function is suitable for development but not for
>   production use. Never serve your static files with Django in a
>   production environment.

Can anyone explain why and how to use it the better way?

EDIT:

Can I use static() with Apache?

Comment: See these tips [here](http://www.tech-wanderings.com/quick-tips-django-and-heroku-static-files-and-multiple-environments)

Comment: @nbryans The tips are interesting, but i can't see an answer to my question in general. It also just tells not to use static files with ´manage.py runserver´. I'd like to understand why i shouldn't use it with Apache?

Comment: If you want to serve static files from your WSGI server, [WhiteNoise](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/) is a better option. If the setup allows it, WhiteNoise will use the webserver to push the actual file content directly from disk using the `sendfile()` system call. The `static()` helper will load the file into python memory and send it through the WSGI handler. These extra layers should be avoided whenever possible, especially for larger files.

Comment: You are still better off using the facilities of a purpose built web server over WhiteNoise. So if using Apache/mod_wsgi use Apache to handle the static files and not WhiteNoise. If using uWSGI or Gunicorn behind nginx, use nginx. One reason why you might still want to use WhiteNoise though is if working in conjunction with a CDN to cache content.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Django is not very fast or efficient for serving static files. To quote the Django docs, "This method is grossly inefficient and probably insecure, so it is unsuitable for production." It is better to use tools that are specifically designed for serving static content. There are extensive instructions for how to setup a static server in the Django documentation on [deploying static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/deployment/).

The basic idea is to not unnecessarily involve Django in the serving of static files. Let your production server, which from your comment it sounds like is apache, serve the static files directly. Here are instructions for editing your httpd.conf file to get apache to serve the static files https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#serving-files. The static() function in django should not be involved at all. Make sure to use the collectstatic management command in django to copy all your static files to the STATIC_ROOT so apache can find them.