# Static files not rendering in Django 2.2 when debug disabled

Tags: python, django, django-2.2

In Django 2.2, when I have `DEBUG=True`, all my static files render fine. But when I set `DEBUG=False` to test my production settings, all static file URLs suddenly return 404 errors.

I have a project structure like:

```
myproject/
    myproject/
        settings.py
        urls.py
    manage.py
static/
    thumbnails/
         image.png
```

My relevant static settings in `settings.py`:

```
 STATIC_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', '..', 'static'))

 INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)
ROOT_URLCONF = 'myproject.urls'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
DEBUG = False
```

And my `urls.py` looks like:

```
import os

from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Why does a url like `http://localhost:8000/static/thumbnails/image.png` work fine when debug is on, but return a 404 when debug is off?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why not serving static files with Django in a production environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38860601/why-not-serving-static-files-with-django-in-a-production-environment)

Comment: Please check that your files are actually copied to `STATIC_ROOT` (have you used `collectstatic`?). Also check in your shell that the value `settings.STATIC_ROOT` matches what you would expect it to be.

Comment: Note that in production you should not have the `static()` url pattern: Django is not efficient at serving static files. Either configure your web server (apache, nginx) to serve the files in `STATIC_ROOT` or use whitenoise behing a CDN. See [my blog post](https://www.dedi.co/blog/entries/2018/12/17/deploying-static-files-aws-django-part-1) on this subject.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In production, you should run `python manage.py collectstatic`, and actually serve your static files from somewhere.

[If you look at the docs for static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files), you'll see

> **Serving the files**
>
> In addition to these configuration steps, you’ll also need to actually
>   serve the static files.
>
> During development, if you use django.contrib.staticfiles, this will
>   be done automatically by runserver when DEBUG is set to True (see
>   django.contrib.staticfiles.views.serve()).
>
> This method is grossly inefficient and probably insecure, so it is
>   unsuitable for production.
>
> See [Deploying static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/deployment/) for proper strategies to serve static files
>   in production environments.

You should set the STATIC_ROOT in you production settings to a folder on you web server, and configure your webserver to point your STATIC_URL to that folder. See [here.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATIC_ROOT)

In your case, it's seems you have taken all these steps, except actually serving your static files. You can do this by pointing your web server to the correct folder, or serving you static files from a CDN or other solution. [Here's how to do it using apache](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#serving-files)

Comment: Alternatively, you can use [django whitenoise](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html) to serve your static files either directly of behind a CDN.

Comment: Interesting. I've always known you should use a CDN or separate host for static files, but it must be a recent change to explicitly disable the staticfiles app when DEBUG=False. In previous releases, I believe it still gave you the option to serve from Django, even if that was inefficient. Good to know.

Comment: Yeah, I had to check as well as I was fairly certain that you could always just serve static files from Django itself, but apparently not

Answer (score 2):

Django was never meant to replace web servers. From the Django docs:

> Django doesn’t serve files itself; it leaves that job to whichever Web server you choose.

This method is grossly inefficient and probably insecure, so it is unsuitable for production.
On `localhost` with `DEBUG = TRUE` it deploys the static file. While on production, you should use your web server(`Apache`, 'Nginx' `etc`) to deploy static files.
Just list the static directory in the configuration file of your web server. More detailed instructions regarding deployment can be found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#serving-files)

Comment: But that's not a reason that it doesn't work, Django **can** serve the static files from STATIC_ROOT, it's just not a good idea to do so.

Comment: @dirkgroten:Just added the reason to my answer.

Comment: But it's not true, if you set the static() url pattern Django will serve static files even if debug is False. Again, you are right that this should not be done on production (although you could actually do that if you go behind a CDN), but it should still work.

Comment: @dirkgroten - `static()` [is a no-op](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/conf/urls/static.py#L10) when `DEBUG = False`. You could use `django.views.static.serve` with `DEBUG = True`, but as Abhyudai says you shouldn't.

Comment: ah, that's correct. I tested it but with whitenoise enabled, forgot about that.